# How do I partially hide Ajax supplied content?

Tags: ajax

I tried hiding the edit, delete, enable and disable links in contact relationships writing an extension in the hook _civicrm_alterContent and injecting jquery:

```
  $content= $content . "
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      CRM.$(document).ready(
        function($) {
          $( '.crm-contact-relationship-links span a:nth-child(2)' ).remove();
          $( '.crm-contact-relationship-links span:nth-child(2)' ).remove();
        }
      );
    </script>
  ";
```

The data I want to hide is supplied through Ajax and apparently out of Jquery's reach because I don't see the desired effect.

Then I tried it using the [dataTable API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24%28%29):

```
        <script type='text/javascript'>

      CRM.$(document).ready(
        function($) {
          var table = $('table.crm-contact-relationship-selector-current').DataTable();
          table.$( '.crm-contact-relationship-links span a:nth-child(2)' ).remove();
          table.$( '.crm-contact-relationship-links span:nth-child(2)' ).remove();
        }
      );
    </script>
```

Without success!

Any suggestion to still reach my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the [Civi JavaScript reference](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Javascript+Reference?desktop=true) , specially this:

```
CRM.$(function($) {

// Your code here

 });
```

> Remember that CRM.$ is our alias of jQuery. So the first line is shorthand notation for CRM.$('document').ready(function($) {
>   The function receives jQuery as it's param, so now we have access to jQuery as the familiar $ for use in our code.

Also make sure you are targeting the right template:  [CRM/Contact/Page/View/RelationshipSelector.tpl](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/templates/CRM/Contact/Page/View/RelationshipSelector.tpl)

A different approach would be to create a custom template as explained [here](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/86213551) and disable the actions links based on $context

**Update**: according to dataTable API, you could do this:

```
CRM.$(function($) {
    var table = $('table.crm-contact-relationship-selector-current').DataTable();
    var column = table.column('.crm-contact-relationship-links');
    column.visible( false );
});
```